# From Generators of Lie Groups to Representations

Tags: lie-algebras

Howard Georgi in his book on Lie algebras mentions a very interesting formula

> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_b}e^{ia_aX_a} = \int_{0}^{1} ds \  e^{isa_aX_a}(iX_b)e^{i(1-s)a_cX_c}.$$

How can one use this formula to derive the Baker Hausdorff formulas and in consequence say calculate a general rotation matrix, $U(\theta) = e^{i\theta_a X_a}$, for spin 1 representation of $\mathrm{SU(2)}$?

Comment: This seems to be a pure math question.

Comment: More specifically which Baker-Hausdorff formulas?

Comment: Say I want to calculate $e^{i(\theta_x J_x + \theta_y J_y + \theta_z J_z)}$

Comment: I do not know, it seems to me a very involved procedure if your goal is to compute that exponential. An explicit formula for $e^{i \theta \sum_{k=1} \sigma_k n_k}$ is instead given by $\cos(\theta)I + i\sin(\theta)\sum_{k=1} ^3\sigma_k n_k$, where $(n_1,n_2,n_3) \in \mathbb R^3$ is any unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to go that painful way.
It pays to collect your $\theta_a \equiv \theta~ n_a$, where $n_a$ are the components of a unit 3-vector $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$.

As a consequence, for spin 1, that is, the triplet representation of SU(2), the celebrated [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) gives 
$$
e^{i\theta(\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})}=I_{3}+i(\boldsymbol{\hat
{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})\sin{\theta}+(\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})^{2}(\cos\theta-1)~.
$$
The reason is that the eigenvalues of $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}$ are the eigenvalues of 
$J_{3}=\mathrm{diag}(1,0,-1)$, and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (dictating this matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation) reduces any  higher power of it to a linear combination of the identity and the first two powers.

It is then straightforward to obtain this expression.

(You might find the compact formula for *any irrep* in [Curtright et al, 2014](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2014/084/).)